# Host file injector with Python

Tags: python, host, hosts-file

I'm having some trouble with a function that's supposed to identify your operating system and return the corresponding PATH to that hosts file so that the program can read the file and add more lines to it. The problem relies when invoking the function into the open() statement as it returns **"TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType"**. Here's my code:

```
import time
import os 
import platform
from datetime import datetime as dt
from sys import platform as _platform

def osFinder():
    if _platform == "Linux" or _platform == "Linux2":
        return "/etc/hosts"
    elif _platform == "darwin":
        return "/etc/hosts"
    elif _platform == "win32":
        return r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
    elif _platform == "win64":
        return r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

# Host Files PATH:
# windows_path = r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
# unix_path = "/etc/hosts"
temp_path = osFinder()

redirect = "127.0.0.1"

sitesList = [
    "www.facebook.com",
    "www.netflix.com",
    "www.youtube.com"
]

from_hour = 7
to_hour = 16

while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, from_hour) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, to_hour):
        print("Working")
        with open(temp_path, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.read()
            for site in sitesList:
                if site in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect + " " + site + "\n")
    else:
        print("Happy Streaming")
        with open(temp_path, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any(site in line for site in sitesList):
                    file.write(line)
            file.truncate()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback so we can track your error.

Comment: I ran the first half of your code and it worked fine. what operating system did you try this on? because you probably should raise an exception if it's not one of the ifs.

Comment: What do you see if you put a call to print the value of _platform at the top of osFinder() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `osFinder`, the platform names are incorrect ([all values in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.platform)). There is no capital at "linux" and "linux2" does not exist anymore since Python 3.3.

I just write the `osFinder`:

```py
from sys import platform as _platform


def osFinder():
    if _platform == "linux":
        return "/etc/hosts"
    elif _platform == "darwin":
        return "/etc/hosts"
    elif _platform == "win32":
        return r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

This can be rewritten in a more pythonic way:

```py
from sys import platform as _platform


PATH_FOR_PLATFORM = {
    "linux": "/etc/hosts", 
    "darwin": "/etc/hosts",
    "win32": r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
}
temp_path = PATH_FOR_PLATFORM[_platform]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I guess I was looking at really old documentation